# best practice for running Laravel 5 site from multiple dev machines

Tags: php, laravel-5

Wondering if anyone has any best practices for running a laravel 5 code set across multiple dev environments...
I was developing something on my Imac, pushed up to github, pulled down from my macbook and now running into all sorts of issues just to get it up and running.

- remade my .env file
- ran composer update to pull down dependencies

Now I am getting some: PDOException in Connector.php line 47 - error. 
Dont know what is going on but would like to know if there is a best practice that maybe i am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Citti

Comment: Are you using Laravel Homestead ?

Comment: That sounds like a `You don't have <insert database solution> installed` error, or even a `Your database wasn't created on <insert database solution>`. Please paste the whole error log for more accurate help. **PS:** You really should use Homestead, as @Kristapsv suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there is no problem with your workflow. Clone repository, recreate `.env` file and, finally, run a `composer install` or a `composer update` to re-install all vendor files locally.

But, when I encounter a problem after configuring a new environment, the most common causes are:

- wrong `.env` parameters
- forget to checkout correct git branch (normally git will clone in `master` branch, so do a `git checkout my-awesome-dev-branch` before testing)
- check if your `config/database.php` uses your `.env` parameters correctly
- wrong apache configuration (like don't enabling `mod_rewrite` and `FollowSymLinks`)
- wrong nginx configuration (like don't enabling pretty urls)
- forget to install `php5-mcrypt` **and enable it** with `php5enmod mcrypt`
- forget to restart webserver when changing things

Comment: after pulling out my hair, figured out it was not reading my .env file! ooo the joy!